# Sending JSON data between two servers with Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, http, server, guzzle

I've edited this question as I realised I was completely on the wrong track, however I still have an issue.

Using Guzzle, how do I send an object in JSON-form from my shop server, which does not use Laravel, to my returns server, which does use Laravel?

I keep receiving the following error:

```
Client error: `POST https://returns.jdoe.blah.test/createReturn` resulted in a `419 unknown status`.
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that I don't have a token, but I don't know what to do with it. I know that Laravel uses CSRF tokens, but my shop server does not use that form.

In the shop server, when a user makes an order, it is saved in the object "$order". I added the following code to order_details.php, in an attempt to pass two particular attributes of the order object:

```
$client = new Client();
$url = "https://returns.jdoe.blah.test/createReturn";
$post_data = array(
    'orderId' => $order['aufnr'],
    'customerId' => $order['kundennummer']
);

$data = json_encode($post_data);

$request = $client->post($url, array(
        'content-type' => 'application/json'
));

$request->setBody($data);

$response = $request->send();
```

Then in my Laravel project, I have:

web.php

```
Route::post('/createReturn', 'ProductReturnsController@createReturn');
```

ProductReturnsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ProductReturn;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductReturnsController extends Controller
{
    public function createReturn($json)
    {
        echo "hallo";

/*        $jsonDecoded = json_decode($json);

        $orderId = $jsonDecoded['orderId'];

        echo $orderId;*/

        return view('data');
    }
}
```

data.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        Test
    </head>

    <body>
        This is a test page.
    </body>
</html>
```

If you need anything else from me to help me solve this, please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

The response to your question is actually on the first page of Guzzle documentation: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

You are doing var_dump($response) which is in fact the response object for the request you made.  That object has a method getBody(),

So try doing

```
dd($response->getBody());
```

instead.

Comment: That doesn't work. I edited my question above to show the output result.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dd($response->getBody()->getContents())` or `dd((string) $response->getBody())`. Response body is a stream object, so if you want a string you have to do an additional method call.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this too and it didn't work. I've completely rephrased my question now, but I still have the same problem.